# What are the different ways of adding a constraint so that only items that are available on the order date can be inserted?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

order.date must be between item.date_from and item.date_to... what are the different ways of doing that?

```
CREATE TABLE "item" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "date_from" DATE NOT NULL,
  "date_to" DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "order" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "date" DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "order_item" (
  "order" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "order",
  "item" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "item" 
);
```

Comment: That's typically a job for a trigger, not a constraint

Comment: How would I add a trigger for that?

Comment: Replacing `date_from` and `date_to` with a single [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) will make the comparison easier. Also avoid `date` as a column name, it is a keyword. Consider the more descriptive `ordered_on`. Avoid quoting column names in definitions, it makes them case-sensitive which will lead to hard to find problems.

Comment: For a trigger see [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) and since you will probably end up using `plpgsql` then [plpgsql Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). Another possibility is have your front end code display only those items in range for the order date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check constraints work on simple expressions. For example, a simple sanity check on the order: `check( date > '2010-01-01')`. There's also [exclusion constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) which check no two rows have the same value as defined by the exclusion. But, with the exception of [foreign key constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK), constraints don't query other tables.

You can solve this with a trigger on `insert` and `update`, and I'll go into that below, but its better to solve this sort of problem with referential integrity. However, I can't think of a way to do that.

---

You can make a view of available items for the order. Here `$1` is the date of the order.

```
create temporary view items_available_to_order
  select *
  -- pluralize table names to avoid conflicting with keywords and columns
  from items
  -- date_from and date_to has become a single daterange when_available
  where items.when_available @> $1
```

Then only insert items from that view.

---

If you want to go the trigger route (you can do both) write a function which checks whether an order's item is valid. It either raises an exception or returns a trigger. `new` is the inserted row, or the row after an update.

I changed some of the table and column names and types to avoid common pitfalls.

```
create function check_item_order_is_valid()
  returns trigger
  language 'plpgsql'
as $body$
declare
  item_is_available boolean;
begin
  select
    items.when_available @> orders.ordered_on into item_is_available
  from item_orders
  join items on items.id = new.order_id
  join orders on orders.id = new.item_id;

  if( not item_is_available) then
    raise exception 'Item #% is not available for order #%',
      new.item_id, new.order_id;
  end if;

  return new;
end
$body$
```

Then define a trigger to call the function when rows are inserted or updated in the item/order table.

```
create trigger check_item_orders
  before insert or update
  on item_orders
  for each row
  execute function check_item_order_is_valid();
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9c846684dafef2dfeba52a9595ce7fd7).

What if the valid range of an item changes? You need an update trigger on item to check that its orders are still valid. Maybe. Depends on your business logic.

Comment: Is going the view route (without a trigger) best practices? What if someone maliciously changed the html form id of an item and added an item that is not available?

Comment: @immortal Triggers provide the strongest protection. The view is my attempt to solve this with referential integrity, but it didn't really work out.

Comment: the SELECT statement is being called for each row. If many rows are being inserted at the same time is there a more efficient way?

Comment: @immortal You could run it `for each statement`, but then the function would have check each row anyway. Don't think of this like running a select in a for loop in a conventional program, doing it inside the database is much more efficient. You could add a `when` clause to only run the function when absolutely necessary. For example, if you put an update trigger on `order` to recheck its items you could add `when old.ordered_on <> new.ordered_on` to only fire when `ordered_on` has changed. [I wouldn't bother right now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Answer (score 0):

A test example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.item_date()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    order_date date;
    from_date date;
    to_date date;
BEGIN
    select into order_date "date" from "order" where id = new.order;
    select into from_date, to_date date_from, date_to from item where id = new.item;
    --Use date range to test whether order date is in item date range.
    if order_date <@ daterange(from_date, to_date, '[]') then
        return new;
    else
        return null;
    end if;
END;
$function$

create trigger item_date_check before insert or update on order_item for each row execute function item_date();

insert into item values (1, '09/01/2021', '10/31/2021');
insert into item values (2, '07/01/2021', '08/31/2021');
insert into "order" values (1, '09/05/2021');

insert into order_item values (1, 1);
NOTICE:  Order date 2021-09-05, from_date 2021-09-01, to_date 2021-10-31
INSERT 0 1

--Returning NULL causes the INSERT not to happen.
insert into order_item values (1, 2);
NOTICE:  Order date 2021-09-05, from_date 2021-07-01, to_date 2021-08-31
INSERT 0 0
```

Note that I had to quote "order" as that is a reserved word also. You might to take a look at [Key(reserved) Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). For `range` functions/operators see [Range Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html). For general information on `range`(s) see [Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)